# Lazy.nvim plugin manager: reference a custom plugin configuration in "dependencies" section

Tags: configuration, neovim

Here is a description of my problem. I want to configure some custom icons for `nvim-web-devicons` plugin. This requires some configuration as shown in the documention. This is easy and I have no problems with this.

Here comes my problem. I want to state `nvim-web-devicons` as a dependency for 2 other plugins, `nvim-tree` and `lualine`. I understand that I can do this with something like this:

```lua
return {
  "nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua",
  lazy = false,
  dependencies = { "nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons" },
  config = function()
    local nvimtree = require("nvim-tree")
  end
```

However, I believe this uses the `nvim-web-devicons` plugin with the default configuration. I want to reference my own configuration that is within the same directory such that my own configuration is pulled in as a dependency. Is there anyway to do this?

I understand that is is possible to import entire directories as a module using `require("path.to.my-module")`, but I don't know if it can be done with individual files.

So basically I want to have a structure like this:

```
nvim/
└── lua/
    └── user/
        ├── core/
        └── plugins/
            ├── nvim-web-devicons.lua -- contains my custom config with icons
            ├── nvim-tree.lua -- dependent on nvim-web-devicons.lua
            └── lualine.lua   -- dependeny on nvim-web-devicons.lua
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to make sure that this is actually causing issues or if you're just asking out of curiosity, because in theory I see no reason why this would be an issue as you currently have it set up. When you specify `dependencies` in Lazy, you're really just telling it that it needs to load that plugin before this plugin. Part of that loading process is loading your custom configuration. The plugin & config will only be loaded once and then all other plugins that depend on it will have access to the custom-configured version (there isn't one version that gets loaded for the `nvim-web-devicons.lua` module and another version that gets loaded for the dependent plugins). It seems that this may be an issue with your `nvim-web-devicons` configuration.

Comment: Hi there, it was a question from curiosity as well as figuring out if this would be a problem or not.
I found out from Reddit that you are correct, Lazy is loading plugin configs and then using the config globally. There is some info on this in [this Reddit question](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/15fgqtl/comment/jueidva/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3). I also asked some AI LLM's and they gave me some good answers related to how using `dependencies` and using `require(some-plugin)` within the `config` function differ slightly for how the plugin is loaded.

Comment: Yes, you always want to use `dependencies` inside Lazy since this will load your plugin and its configuration. `require` won't actually "load" the plugin at all, it will just make its lua module available to use in your code, so without loading the plugin using your package manager, `require` won't find the module.